# Use MVVM Cross to bind an XML string formatted at run time to an Android TextView

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MVVM Cross in Xamarin Studio:

I have a text view, and I want to do something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb1"
        local:MvxBind="FormattedText Item.Description;"
         />
```

Where Item.Description is set at runtime, and is equal to something like:

```
"<b>The header</b>\\n\\nThe sub text"
```

or another formatted string.

I am aware I can do this if the text string is static by using a resource file, but my text is not static.

Bonus points if you give me a solution that would work in Android and iOS XML!

Comment: Can't you use a MvxValueConverter to format the string in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a great time to learn about [MvvmCross Value Converters](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters).
From the Wiki:

> Value Converters in MvvmCross are used to provide mappings to/from
>   logical values in the view models and presented values in the user
>   interface.

In this case you can make a new class inherited from `MvxValueConverter` and override the `Convert` method. You will do the string formatting inside the `Convert` method.  Then in your binding you can reference the Value Converter and MvvmCross will automatically call the Value Converter before it displays the bound data.

Here is an example Value Converter which takes a `float?` as input and outputs a formatted currency `string`:

```
public class CurrencyValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<float?, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(float? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value.HasValue ? null : string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", value.Value);
    }
}
```

Then inside the AXML you can reference the Value Converter using the following syntax:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="[CashOnDeliveryCharges]"
            local:MvxBind="Text Currency(CashOnDeliveryCharges), FallbackValue='N/A'" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer [Trevor: http://stackoverflow.com/users/186046/trevor-balcom], it was really helpful. To those users who need formatting not possible in C Sharp cross platform in a non Xamarin Forms app, such as bold or underline, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who require simple formatting such as adding dashes to phone numbers etc, see Trevor's excellent and informative answer above.

If you need things like bold, underline etc, and you're working cross platform in MVVM Cross but without the aid of Xamarin forms, you'll need to use raw XML and android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/the_id_of_the_previous_element" in combination with things like android:textStyle="bold"

E.g

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        local:MvxBind="Text YourPropertyToBind;"
        />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id1"
        android:text="the_second_bit_of_text_this_is_static_not_bound_if_you_want"
        />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        local:MvxBind="Text The_Next_Bit_Of_Text;"
        />
```